# AngularJS variable not updating between functions

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS and not sure what i'm doing wrong.

I am trying to implement an edit modal window so I am making a copy of the element to edit, then trying to access it once an image upload i done to update the image src, but for some reason the scope variable is empty in the upload function.
What am i doing wrong ?

```
app.controller('projectsController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $modal) {

    $scope.edit = function(index){
        $scope.tempObj = angular.copy($scope.projects[index]);                      
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'projects/_edit_project',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                obj: function () { return $scope.tempObj; }
            }         
        }).result.then(function (project) { $scope.projects[index] =    project });
    }       

    $scope.processFileUpload = function(){
        console.log($scope.tempObj)    <--THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED                
    }



    var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, obj) {        
        $scope.obj = obj;       
        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close($scope.obj);
        };
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };          
    };

}
```

Comment: Are you sure $scope.projects[index] returns something when the edit function is called?

Comment: Yes, I'm actually using the resolved variable "obj" in the view and the data is there. Also checked the console.log to make sure and $scope.tempObj shows the correct object in the edit() function

Comment: Can you show us where `edit` and `processFileUpload` is called?

Comment: I added more code to show the main controller and the modal controller. Not sure if that's the best method to define it, I basically followed how they did in the docs: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: Erm. Try creating the `modalInstanceCtrl` outside the scope of the `projectsController`. Also, instead of `$scope.obj = obj` try `$scope.data = { obj: obj}`